# Trying to access restricted resource as (anonymous) produces 404 error, not 401

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-user-groups

I have a resource group called 'Front End Users'. I want any non-signed-in (aka (anonymous)) users to be redirected to an unauthorised (401) page.

I have set that page in the System Settings `unauthorized_page` option, and have set up the (anonymous) User Group to have a 'Load Only' access for the resource group 'Front End Users':

[image]

But it still redirects to my `error_page` resource instead of `unauthorized_page`.

Would anyone know where I have gone wrong? Have I missed a step?

(I am using Revo 2.2.10)

Answer (score 2):

Its working as intended since resource groups dont restrict access per say but actually hide the resource from existance if u dont have access. If you want to manage pages with 401 and login prompts you want to skip resource groups and instead use the Login snippet with its accessories.

Edit: obviously youre using the Login snippet already, but to achieve wat youre looking for the easiest way would be to remove the resource groups and instead apply a "member page" template to resources that should be hidden, by placing the `isLoggedIn` snippet (part of Login package) at the top of the template.

Comment: This is by design indeed.

Comment: That seems odd as I followed the instructions here: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/security/security-tutorials/more-on-the-anonymous-user-group

Comment: Hmmm, i've never gotten it to work but if youve flushed permissions i dont see what else there is to try :/ double check so you actually have the right unauthorized page specified and that the unauthorized page isnt protected by a resource group!